# How to retrive friends email id from connections

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, connection, friend

How to retrive friends email id  from connections. using API.We are using auth for the development purpose.

With Regards
Gurudath

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully, this is not possible for privacy reasons. You can only get the email of the authorized user with the email permission.